# Deploying play! to heroku

Tags: git, deployment, heroku, playframework

I'm following [this](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play) tutorial on how to deploy my play! app to heroku.  I haven't used git, foreman, or heroku before.  When I get to the part that says to enter

```
gem install foreman
foreman start
```

I'm rather confused.  First of all, gem isn't a recognized command and I have no idea what it is.  I have a Foreman directory that heroku installed for me in Program Files.  What is Foreman even necessary for here? Is it what runs the Procfile I created earlier in the tutorial?

Also, if I just skip this part of the tutorial and go on, when I get to the git push, when I enter the command:

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the error messages:

```
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I haven't dealt with git up until today, so I'm unfamiliar with what exactly the command is trying to do.  Is it failing because I skipped the earlier step?

Comment: Can you do a `git remote -v` and make sure the `heroku` remote is there?  If you had a git repo when you ran `heroku create -s cedar` then the git remote should have been automatically added to your git config.

Comment: I thought I had done this, but I tried again with another app and it all went through fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error means you do not have a git remote named "heroku". When you type `heroku create -s cedar`, a git remote called "heroku" is added to your `.git/config file`. If you create an app without having created a git repo first, the remote will not be created; it will only be displayed on the command line. If you know the name of your app, you can add the git remote with, `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:appname.git`. Otherwise, you can create a new app, or run `heroku apps` and figure out the app name.

Also, regarding foreman, the Heroku toolbelt installs all the heroku related tools (except for git) that you should need:
http://toolbelt.heroku.com/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you uploaded your public key to heroku.

Make sure you added the remote with

```
git remote add heroku ssh://...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be

> git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:appname.git

Where appname is the name of your app.

Then:

> git push heroku master

(assuming you want to push the master branch)